# Is there is any way to capture print() statement during integration test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

Is there is any way during the integration testing to monitor or save or read whatever the print() statement is printing to the console. I m using `integration_test` for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you?

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final printed = <String>[];
  final result = runZoned(() => foo(), zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(
    print: (self, parent, zone, line) {
      printed.add(line);
    },
  ));

  print('Result: $result');
  print('Printed:\n${printed.join('\n')}');
  debugger();
}

int foo() {
  print('Hello');
  print('Goodbye');
  return 41;
}
```

P.S.
I added a `debugger` call so that the result of the work was visible. This statement can (and should) be removed.